# Group_by gives error "no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "list"

Tags: r, error-handling, group-by, tidyr

I am trying to group by and sum. My code is:

```
supply_agg = vector(length = 64, mode = 'list')
for (i in 1:64) {
  supply_agg[[i]] <- PST[rownames(pct_kritiek),]*pct_kritiek[,i] *1000000
  supply_agg[[i]] <- cbind("gg_omschrijving" = rownames(supply_agg[[i]]), supply_agg[[i]])
  supply_agg[[i]] <- inner_join(koppelGG, supply_agg[[i]], by= "gg_omschrijving")
  supply_agg[[i]] <- supply_agg[[i]][,-1]
  supply_agg[[i]] <- supply_agg[[i]] %>% 
    group_by(gg_mm) %>% 
    summarise_each(funs(sum))
  colnames(supply_agg[[i]]) <- koppelRK[1,]
  supply_agg[[i]]<- pivot_longer(supply_agg[[i]], col= "Landbouw, bosbouw en visserij":"Milieu",names_to = "Regkol", values_to = "value")
  supply_agg[[i]]<- supply_agg[[i]][,-3]
  supply_agg[[i]] <- supply_agg %>% 
    group_by(gg_mm, Regkol) %>%
    summarise_each(funs(sum()))
```

It all goes well(including the first group_by) until that last group_by, which gives:

> "no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class
> "list".

[data just before last group_by](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mganN.png)

In the image you can see how the data looks just before the group_by function. I need to group when "gg_mm" and "Regkol" are the same.

Comment: Please provide a minimal reporducible example along with a description of the desired output/result. The error is relatively clear. Your code creates a list which can‘t be handled by the group_by function.

Comment: I just joined this forum. How to provide sample data? It is also difficult to do because its confidential data (because of work) And how come the first group_by function works, but the second (after pivot_longer) does not work.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. If your data is confidential, try to create a toy data set tha mimics the structure of your data, or maybe you can provide just a small subset of your data and replace some values by random values.

Comment: Please create a small but reproducible example of your data using `dput`. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269) link explains that in more detail. Keep only the columns that are required for the question and drop others. Also show us expected output for the data you share. You don't have to share your actual data you can create a fake dataset that is similar to your original dataset but make sure that dataset covers all possible scenarios that are present in your original set so that we don't have a situation where the answer works on the fake dataset but not on real dataset.